# How to insert output of Lua script verbatim at location with LuaLaTeX?

Tags: luatex, lua

I'm using TikZ' graph layout engine, and I'm very confused as to why

```
\graph {1, 2, 3, 2--3};
```

draws the desired graph, while

```
\graph {\directlua{dofile("foo.lua")}};
```

does not when foo.lua just contains

```
tex.print("1, 2, 3, 2--3")
```

I'm obviously very confused with regards to `\directlua`…

**Edit:** In the latter case I simply get the text "1, 2, 3, 2–3" as if my graph contained a single node with that label.

**Edit 2:** Here's a near-minimal working example. Sorry for not posting it earlier.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing}

\begin{document}

This works as expected:\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph {1,2,3, 2--3};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}

This does not:\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph {\directlua{dofile("foo.lua")}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The file foo.lua consists of the single line `tex.print("1,2,3, 2--3")`.

Compiling the TeX file with lualatex produces the following:

[image: Result of compilation]

Comment: Have you tried placing a function in the external file (all the function has to do is run `tex.print("1, 2, 3, 2--3")`), loading the external file via a `dofile` call, and then executing the function via a `\directlua` instruction?

Comment: Just tried. The result is the same. I just get the text "1, 2, 3, 2–3" rendered, as if I wanted a single node named that.

Comment: please post a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001).

Comment: @Mico: Sorry, I've added that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not hide the tikz syntax behind expansion whether lua or a tex macro. this works:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \expandafter\graph\expandafter {\directlua{dofile("foo.lua")}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```